# Sending a file from an iPhone to a Raspberry Pi via Bluetooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, linux, bluetooth

I am considering extending an application I have created on a Raspberry Pi running Raspian to use an iPhone/iPad. I keep getting mixed messages when I am searching so I wanted to ask:

I would like to be able to send a file FROM my iPhone/iPad to a Raspberry Pi via Bluetooth, is this possible without jailbreaking the phone? The file transfer only has to be one way, so the iPhone/iPad does not need to receive/read files at all from the Raspberry Pi, it just has to send them.

The file will be very small and just be full of a little text based off of user input on the iPhone/iPad to be read and used on the Raspberry Pi.

Unfortunately for what I want to do, Android is not an alternative option (which is a shame because I have a feeling my life would be so much easier if it was).

Thank you for your time, and sorry if this is a silly question, I am still new to iOS programming.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. I tried searching for AirDrop but it seems to be something else. I want to just send photos.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Hi @Dellgloom, Did you find any solution???